# How to handle null values in custom function?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to add a custom column to combine values of 2 columns (Col3 and Col4) with the result of a custom function `fnMyFunction()` in this way

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Custom Column", 
     each 
      Text.Combine( 
        {
            [Col3],
            [Col4],
            fnMyFunction([Col5],[Col6])
         }
        )),
```

I'm getting this error when function handles null values

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text.
Details:
    Value=
    Type=[Type]
```

The function `fnMyFunction` is like this:

```
(input1 as text, input2 as text)=>
let
    Inputs = {input1, input2},
    SplitAndZip = List.Zip(List.Transform(Inputs, each Text.ToList(_))),
    OtherStep
    ...
    ..
    LastStep
in
    LastStep
```

I've tried to add the `if else` in `Input` step in order to get empty as output for the function but doesn't work

```
(input1 as text, input2 as text)=>
let
    Inputs = if input1 <> null then {input1, input2} else {"",""}, //Added "if else" here
    SplitAndZip = List.Zip(List.Transform(Inputs, each Text.ToList(_))),
    OtherSteps
    ...
    ..
    LastStep
in
    LastStep
```

How can be fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function definition to be the following:

```
(optional input1 as text, optional input2 as text)=>
```

Comment: See `Optional Parameters` section https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/28/4199/power-query-m-primer-part2-functions-defining

Answer (score 0):

1. PQ has a null-coalesce operator `??`. Try this:
   `Inputs = {input1 ?? "", input2 ?? ""}`

> edit from the future - #2 is wrong. My bad. Still, read Ben's guide. It's the best PQ text-book there is.

2. Once you fix the fn, `each... Combine([col3],[col4]..)` will break because you forgot to `_` before [col3] and [col4]. `each..._` is syntactic sugar for a single-argument function (eating a whole row, in this case). See here: **https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/12/08/4270/power-query-m-primer-part3-functions-function-values-passing-returning-defining-inline-recursion**

Comment: Thanks for answer. I´ve added what you suggested `Inputs = {input1 ?? "", input2 ?? ""}` but still I get the error. I didn't understand what to do for what you mentioned in item 2.

Comment: Yup, my bad on the `_[ ]`. PQ will try and access the column value from the record that is passed to it in a general namespace. So `_[col3]` = `[col3]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
each try Text.Combine() otherwise ""
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion but I got error like `TRY` and `OTHERWISE` are not understood

Comment: That's because `try` and `otherwise` need to be lowercase